# Mono/Cygwin Issue?

Tags: c#, vb.net, gcc, mono, cygwin

I am trying to remove the dependencies of my `.net` app by using `mono` and `cygwin`.

For more info look [here](https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/83774-Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeit-vom-Framework/?postID=883602#post883602).

I installed all the packages, `gcc`, `gcc-core`, `as`.

Then I navigated to my `vb.net` application with the `cygwin` terminal.
I tried to merge all the dependencies with this command:

```
mkbundle -o Mono/MsgBox.exe MsgBox.exe --deps -z
```

The application itself is just a simple module displaying a MessageBox.
When I now hit enter in the Cygwin Console to merge the .net framework dependencies, it starts merging...

[image]

and then it gives me this error:

[image]

I already did some research, and found out that this has something to do with the new `MinGW` compiler, and its possible to change the settings somehow.

The `MsgBox` app itself works fine, I only want to merge the dependencies as explained in the tutorial above.

Can someone please explain me how I can fix this compiling error?

Comment: The problem is still unsolved. Anyone who has the same Problem and maybe knows a solution?

Comment: Have you tried [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630)?

Comment: I can use it to embed dlls, but not the whole framework. ;) Other ideas?

Comment: Hi. As far as I can see you should edit the following file: cygwin\lib\python2.7\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py (your python version might be different, so better search for the file 'cygwinccompiler.py' in your filesystem). There, search for -mno-cygwin (around line 294) and remove it blank. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have downloaded cygwin 64 bit and your application is 32 bit. I have faced this error and downloaded cygwin 32 now everything works fine.
Please let me know if this was helpful :)

Comment: That didn't solve the problem but maybe you can help me setting up everything in a virtual machine via TeamViewer?